# Is BufferedReader.readLine() over a Socket a blocking operation?

Tags: java, sockets, stream, observable

I'm trying to get to run an example class that uses an `Observer` interface and an `Observable` subclass to check when the input stream from the socket is different from a null string. Here is the code (`Observable` class):

```
@Override
public void run() {
    String input;
    while (true) {
        try {
            input = reader.readLine();
            if (input != null) {
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(input);
            } else
                System.out.println("Nothing read from the stream");
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

So, when the condition `input != null` is true, then the `update()` method is called and it outputs to the `stdout` what has been read from the socket. The server is sending a string every second and the observer checks it at max speed (without any `sleep()` calls). So, what really `BufferedReader.readLine()` does when reading from a stream that is owned by a socket? Because the `else` block is never executed.

Answer (score 1):

As [BufferedReader.readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) states

> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

You will only get `null` when the other end closes the connection.

If you want to implement a busy waiting strategy, you could use non-blocking NIO, but be aware that this will use 100% of one CPU.

Comment: Okay thanks, now i can make this to work in another way

Comment: where's the code anyway?

Comment: @gumuruh the only code is in the OP

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a `BufferedReader` around a socket as a `BufferedReader` simply wraps another `Reader`. `Reader`s don’t support non-blocking I/O at all.

Before you can create a `BufferedReader`, you have to create a `Reader`:

[`Channels.newReader(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newReader-java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel-java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder-int-):

> …if the channel is in non-blocking mode when bytes are to be read then an `IllegalBlockingModeException` will be thrown.

The similar thing will happen if you try [the detour via an `InputStream`, e.g. acquired by `Socket.getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream--):

> If the channel is in non-blocking mode then the input stream's read operations will throw an `IllegalBlockingModeException`.

So you can use `BufferedReader.readLine()` only when the socket is in blocking mode which implies that it will wait until at least one character could be read which is a different condition than end-of-stream. Hence, as [Peter Lawrey pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32078666/2711488), it will continue to read until either the line is complete or the stream reaches its end which implies in a blocking socket that the stream has been closed.

Comment: Doing that thing in your way. What i need to do is understand via code when there's no input

Comment: What I tried to explain is that there is no “no input” condition when using `Reader`s or `InputStream`s. They only support blocking I/O which implies waiting until at least one `byte`/`char` could be read. For non-blocking I/O you have to use `Channel`s directly, but there is no non-blocking equivalent to a `Reader` so you would have to do the entire charset conversion and scanning for an end-of-line manually. Providing such a solution would exceed the scope of SO.

Comment: Okay sorry, now i can understand